# Movie about a monster that eats people and excrete the undigested jewelries of the victims on a church altar

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

This is a weird movie where they searched this empty city where the inhabitants are missing, during searching they found jewelries & metal objects on a church altar which at first they thought that it's an offering of some sort, but turns out it's just the monster pooping undigested materials.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like the 1998 film [Phantoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantoms_(film)) based on the Dean Koontz novel of the same name.

In this case the monster not only kills and eats people it absorbs their thoughts and fears. The victims, not knowing what it is, think it is a demon or Satan.  Thus, in addition to leaving all the items on the altar the titular monster in the movie after killing the church full of people, thinks that is what it is. It decides it needs a gospel of its own.

If this is the movie you may also remember a scene in which severed heads of the town baker and his wife are found in an oven.

Does that sound familiar?

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/222856/23243

Comment: Agreed.  I had the same thought. But the part about the church and the leftover objects doesn't seem to be mentioned in the link.  So wasn't sure if the OP would recognize the references and thought it might help to provide the additional detail here.

Comment: Totally agreed, and we might want to make the other one a dupe of this one, especially if it expands on it. :)