Sci-fi movie - men in a bar in a small town, trapped by an alien
OK, I'm desperate for help on this, my father was watching this movie when I was a kid. I couldn't have been more than five or six, maybe seven, years old, around 1995. I only remember a couple scenes from the movie. It was set in a small town. The first scene I can remember is a group of men inside of what looks like a bar and something appears in the window and they all shoot it. One of them says "I think we got it". He strolls over to the window to look out and whatever it was reaches up, grabs and yanks him out and kills him.
The next scene I remember is they see him alive inside again of this bar whatever it is but his lower half is this alien monster thing and it's crawling across the floor and his upper torso and arms are completely normal. I remember as it's crawling towards these guys, he says "Did you slip me a Mickey?".
The next scene I remember is another small town bar somewhere in this lady is sitting down drinking a beer at the bar watching the TV and the TV is talking about some crazy thing that happened in some small town. The lady says something about crazy small towns and the guy sitting next to turns to her and he is the half alien half man from the small town. But he looks completely normal and he’s got this creepy look on his face and he says to her "lady, do you wanna see something real crazy?"
So those are the scenes that I can remember again I was a kid and my dad was watching this on TV or something, So these scenes have been rattling around in my head for the past 30 years please anybody help me, as I'm descending into madness here. It's got a real feel of like an 80s sci-fi movie or something like that.

Thirty years you waited. Answered within two minutes on SFF:SE. There's a lesson to be learned here...

This is Phantoms (1998).

In the peaceful town of Snowfield, Colorado something evil has wiped out the community. And now, its up to a group of people to stop it, or at least get out of Snowfield alive.


The script contains all of the lines you've mentioned.

You girls slip me a Mickey?

And

You want to see something?

And

I think we got it.

Trailer




If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/222856/late-90s-movie-about-people-disappearing-down-drains-i-believe
